# Cannot handle bad decrypt error when encryption key is wrong node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, encryption

I am creating 2 functions to encrypt / decrypt a file. for now, they work when the password is right (the encryption key is derived with a key derivation function from the password). But when the input password is wrong the function throws an error.

I want that when the password is wrong, the returning function resolves to false, handles the error and doesn't crash the app.

this is the code:

```
function decrypt(path: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {
  let reader = fs.createReadStream(path);
  let salt: Buffer, iv: Buffer;

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    reader.on("readable", () => {
      if (!salt) salt = reader.read(SALT_LENGTH);
      if (!iv) iv = reader.read(IV_LENGTH);

      if (salt && iv) {
        reader.close();
      }
    });

    reader.on("close", async () => {
      reader = fs.createReadStream(path, { start: SALT_LENGTH + IV_LENGTH });

      let key = await deriveKey(password, salt.toString("ascii"));
      let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);

      decipher.on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
        res(false);
      });

      let tmpPath = path + ".tmp";
      let writer = fs.createWriteStream(tmpPath);

      reader
        .pipe(decipher)
        .on("error", (err) => {
          rej(err);
          res(false);
        })
        .pipe(writer);

      writer.on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
        res(false);
      });

      writer.on("finish", async () => {
        await deleteFile(path);
        await renameFile(tmpPath, path);
        res(true);
      });
    });
  });
}

encrypt("test.txt", "password")
  .then(() => decrypt("test.txt", "passworddd"))
  .then(console.log);
```

i have tried everything:

- wrapping the code in a try catch
- on every pipe function add a error handler
- add an error handler on the decipher

the example call does not log anyhing. it just crashes.

how can i handle the bad decrypt error?

this is the error:

```
Error: error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv._flush (node:internal/crypto/cipher:165:29)
    at Decipheriv.final [as _final] (node:internal/streams/transform:132:10)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:757:12)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:769:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:779:5)
    at Decipheriv.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:687:5)
    at ReadStream.onend (node:internal/streams/readable:756:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:domain:488:12) {
  library: 'Provider routines',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_BAD_DECRYPT'
}
```

Comment: Your question should include the actual error/exception thrown, and also note *where* in the code the exception happens.

Comment: `wrapping the code in a try catch` where? you probably did it wrong.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I edited my question. The problem is that i am quite the noob regarding crypto / encryption and streams, so i cannot figure put when the exception is being thrown

Comment: by the way, once you `rej(err);` there's no need to `res(false)` ... since a Promise can only be "settled" once

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried inside the error handlers, outside the error handlers, wrapping the entire function, wrapped the on readable, inside the on readable. i just cant figure it out

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you very much. I am trying to learn to use Promises since they seem very useful

Comment: also, you have no `catch` on `encrypt` promise chain